# UK date formatting c#

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2012

```
DateTime Test;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true)
```

I have this so I can just get the dates instead of DateTime, but I need UK(DD/MM/YYYY) format and when I try it I get an error saying conversion failed

Comment: And why don't you adjust your date mask format to the one expected?

Comment: What is the value of `txtDOB.Text` exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> I have this so I can just get the dates instead of DateTime, but I
>   need UK(DD/MM/YYYY) format

*Well*, if I understand it, you just need to use `dd/MM/yyyy` (there is no `DD` and `YYYY` format in custom date and time formatting) format instead of `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Successfull
}
```

But remember, [`"/"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and time format strings. It means as; *replace me with the current culture or specified culture date separator*. That means if your current culture doesn't have `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx), your parsing will fail since you using `null` as a `IFormatProvider` which is equivalent to use [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also since [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `boolean`, there is no point compare with an another `boolean`.

What I try to say; just use

```
if(true)
{

}
```

instead of

```
if(true == true)
{

}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP has tried your suggestion but he has used the upper case mask. DD/MM/YYYY and of course this gives the error in the TryParse

Comment: @Steve I strongly suspect it neither. Would be much better to give exact solution if we know what is `txtDOB.Text` and `CurrentCulture` values :) And little bit a clear question of course.

Comment: @SonerGönül the txtDOB.Text value is someone entering their date of birth into a database

Comment: @user3895591 Sure.. But what is the format of it? If you want to parse it, your string and format should match **exactly**.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Test.Date
```

to give you the date as you said you wanted and then use .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") to get UK DateTime

```
Test.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: `Test` is an `out` parameter here. If the conversation will fail, it will be `DateTime.MinValue`. I think OP can't parse with `dd/MM/yyyy` format instead of can or can't get string representation of it. Feel like you missed the point.

Comment: Ah yes I see. The question is very poor, it is easy to miss the point

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DateTime Test;
var date = "06/08/2014".Replace('/', '.');
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test);
```

Comment: What is the month value and the day value in your results? OP wants dd/MM/yyyy. Your answer give him the same result.